# Is it possible to convert an XML file created in actionscript to a FileReference object?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a working s3 uploader in actionscript that uses the FileReference class so a user can browse for files to upload when he/she clicks on the upload button.

I have a web application and I want the user to have his/her configuration saved to s3 as an XML file when they hit the save button, so the "save" button will trigger the upload. However, i cant figure out a way to add the XML file to the FileReference variable I create. I was looking at the File class but that appears to be only usable in AIR.

Is it possible to create a FileReference object based off of an XML file that actionscript creates within the application without browsing for a file using FileReference.browse(); ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm sure it's possible but is it the best strategy :)

How about posting the XML to a web service (perhaps hosted on Heroku for free) and then have the web service save the XML to S3 or a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my original question is "no". According to this [article](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2008/08/20/reading-and-writing-local-files-in-flash-player-10/) by Mike Chambers, you cant.

It is apparently a sandbox issue so that a malicious flash program will not be able to do anything related to saving files without a users permission.

Comment: This is not correct. The sandbox issue only applies to read/write of local files. As stated in your question you are trying to append data to a file being uploaded. Any and all local file access MUST be triggered by user interaction IE: mouse click. once that event is in the stack then you can access a file that the user selects. This however still has limitations.